# convert HTML entities in a JSON

Tags: json, jq

I have a this kind of awful JSON file `{ "foo": "bar &rsquo; foo &rsquo;" }`.

Is there a way - using preferably jq - to convert the HTML entities then in this example to convert `&rsquo;` in `’`.

I need to convert them programmatically. This JSON is only an example.

Thank you

Comment: Do you just need to convert the entities in the JSON file for personal use or do you need to convert them programmatically for some purpose? Please edit your question for clarity.

Comment: For example, if you just need the JSON files entities converted into text for some other purpose you could just copy/paste into this tool: https://mothereff.in/html-entities

Comment: Hi @StephenMIrving I need to convert them programmatically. That is only an example

Comment: OK, well that online tool uses a repository written in JavaScript that I have linked in an answer below. Use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy-to-use HTML entity encoder/decoder called `he` that was written in JavaScript. It is *not* `jq` based, but it should allow you to do what you are attempting with relative ease.

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he

**INSTALL:**

Via npm:

`npm install he`

Via Bower:

`bower install he`

Via Component:

`component install mathiasbynens/he`

In a browser:

```html
<script src="he.js"></script>
```

In Node.js, io.js, Narwhal, and RingoJS:

```js
var he = require('he');
```

In Rhino:

`load('he.js');`

Using an AMD loader like RequireJS:

```
require(
  {
    'paths': {
      'he': 'path/to/he'
    }
  },
  ['he'],
  function(he) {
    console.log(he);
  }
);
```

**Using as a CLI tool:**

Install `he` using the `-g` global flag

`npm i -g he`

You will be then able to encode or decode HTML entities from the command line:

```sh
$ he --encode 'föo ♥ bår  baz'
> f&#xF6;o &#x2665; b&#xE5;r &#x1D306; baz

$ he --encode --use-named-refs 'föo ♥ bår  baz'
> f&ouml;o &hearts; b&aring;r &#x1D306; baz

$ he --decode 'f&ouml;o &hearts; b&aring;r &#x1D306; baz'
> föo ♥ bår  baz
```

**Decoding Programmatically:**

```js
he.decode(html, options)
```

This function takes a string of HTML and decodes any named and numerical character references in it using the algorithm described in section 12.2.4.69 of the HTML spec.

```js
he.decode('foo &copy; bar &ne; baz &#x1D306; qux');
// → 'foo © bar ≠ baz  qux'
```

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: The question is asking how to do this using `jq` so explaining how to integrate the library you recommend with `jq` would probably be useful.

Comment: I see your point, but the link has pretty detailed documentation on how to integrate it. Should I have copy/pasted the entire readme.md into my answer? He didn't include any information as to how he was going to use it that would have allowed me to fine tune what part of the documentation he needed.